How is schema used in Azure Data Studio
I had thought that a database schema was the name of the structure on which tables are interconnected by primary keys and foreign keys.  But in the tool, Azure Data Studio, the user is asked to select from a pre-defined set of schemas when creating a table.  What is more is that when setting up or createing a database through Azure, we are given the opportuniityh to use a sample database and this is where "SalesLT" comes from and so there must be some place where we can define a schema with Azure Data Studio.  Where would that be?  It was generated when deciding to use a demo sample database.  So there must be some way, using SQL code or otherwise, to generate a schema.


Regardless of the IDE you use, ADS, SSMS, Visual Studio, DBeaver, a schema is the same thing; that you're using ADS as you're chosen IDE doesn't change what it is.

Does this answer your question? what exactly is database schema?

Does this answer your question? What good are SQL Server schemas?


there must be some place where we can define a schema with Azure Data Studio.

The Schema in SQL is comprising a set of database elements such as tables, triggers, stored procedures, and more. Each schema is associated with a user who serves as the schema owner.
In Azure data studio You need to generate the schema using CREATE SCHEMA statement in current database.
CREATE SCHEMA schemaname
   [AUTHORIZATION ownername]

You can see schema is created and in added in dropdown while creating table.

